# TCP接続切断時のandroid端末⇒サーバへのFINが遅延する

Tags: android, tcp

android端末のアプリ使用でTCP切断時、正常であれば『サーバ⇒端末』にFINが投げられた後、即『端末⇒サーバ』へFINを返しています。
ただ時たま、『サーバ⇒端末』にFINが投げられた後、『端末⇒サーバ』へFINを返す際に120sほどかることがあります。

こちら、遅れる原因としてどういったものが考えられますでしょうか。
OSの問題でしょうか。
※端末アプリにはHTTPリクエスト時の共通処理として、ソケットのクローズ処理があります

Comment: どちらかというとネットワークの問題ではないでしょうか？無線通信などでパケットロス率が高ければ、ACK応答遅延は特に珍しくないと思います。

Answer (score 1):

AndroidOSに搭載されているTCPプロトコルのソフトウェアのバグの可能性も否定出来ませんが
TCPのクローズ処理のシーケンスとして以下のような流れになります。

サーバ：FIN（これをもってサーバからデータ送信しない） -> ACK応答（OKわかった。でもクライアントはまだ送信するかもしれないよ）
クライアント：FIN（これをもってクライアントからデータ送信しない） -> ACK応答（OKわかった）
サーバ・クライアント：双方FINを認識したのでじゃあクローズとしよう。

つまり、『サーバ -> 端末』でのFIN時点ではTCP切断は成立していません。（shutdown状態）
また、サーバ側はsend()する事は出来ませんが、shutdown(読込)していなければrecv()は可能）ですし
クライアント側はsend()もrecv()もする事が出来ます。但し、使用しているソケットに対して
クライアントがrecv()をした時、TCPプロトコル側に"**受信データがない**"と戻り値として「0」が返ります。（もうサーバから送られる可能性が無いので）

なのでクライアントからのFINが遅れる原因として考えられる可能性は、
クライアント側がclose()またはshutdown(書込）を実行してサーバ側にFIN送信をしていないのではないでしょうか。
具体的にはクライアント側がまだ受信処理をしている、とか送信処理をしているとか。（まだ仕事をしている）
またはクライアント側のアプリケーションの問題で適切にclose()を発行していないのかもしれませんね。
話を聞く限り、120秒も掛かっているのでTCPプロトコルかアプリケーションの何らかの問題の可能性が高いかもしれません。
設定にもよりますが120秒という切りの良い時間ですし、サーバ側が実行したclose()がタイムアウトして切断が成立しているのかもしれません。
パケットキャプチャ見ないとわかりませんが、サーバがclose()でタイムアウト（TIME-WAIT2 -> CLOSED）になった後にクライアントからデータ送信が来た場合RSTを返すはずなので
そういう動きになっていればclose()のタイムアウトで強制切断になっている可能性が高いと思います。